# Patching AIX binary

Tags: aix, patch

I am attached to a running proces using dbx on AIX. There is a bug in the program, the offset in the opcode below is 0x9b8, but should be 0xbe8:

(dbx) listi 0x100001b14
0x100001b14 (..........+0x34) e88109b8             ld   r4,0x9b8(r1)

I am able to fix that using the command below:

(dbx) assign 0x100001b14 = 0xe8810be8

but that affects only the running process and its memory. How can I change the on disk binary? I am not able to locate the pattern e88109b8 in the binary file,
otherwise I would use e.g. dd utility to patch it.

Best regards,
Pavel Filipensky

Comment: I guess the executable file is simply mapped into virtual memory, so memory address 0x100001b14 is file address 0x1b14 Of course you have to check this first: `od -Ax -tx1 yourexename | grep ^001b10`

Comment: Yes, excatly. 0x1b14  (decimal 6932) was the offest. Thanks!